How to specify weekday?
I'm trying to create yearly recurring event that occurs on 4th weekday of January. If I create a rule like this
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=4;BYMONTH=1;COUNT=2
Then it creates on Sat Jan 4th, 2025 and Sun Jan 4th, 2026.
But by weekday I mean Monday to Friday. So I want to create Monday Jan 6th, 2025 and Tuesday Jan 6th, 2026. I'm not able to figure out the rrule to do this.
